# Azure 1.4 MVC3 session state and caching

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, session, azure, session-state

I'm having trouble implementing a session state with Azure cache, when running on multiple instances.
This is what I did while following various tutorials:

1 - set up caching: I've added a caching service in the old azure management portal, I couldn't find caching options in the new portal

2 - update the web.config to include the following:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="dataCacheClients"
           type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientsSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core"
           allowLocation="true"
           allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
</configSections>

<dataCacheClients>
  <dataCacheClient name="default">
    <hosts>
      <host name="superSecretName.cache.windows.net" cachePort="22233" />
    </hosts>
    <securityProperties mode="Message">
      <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="superSecretAuthToken"></messageSecurity>
    </securityProperties>
  </dataCacheClient>
</dataCacheClients>

<system.web>
  <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider"
           type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache"
           cacheName="default"
           useBlobMode="true" 
           dataCacheClientName="default" />
    </providers>
  </sessionState>
</system.web>
```

3 - dance a happy dance, until everything crashes and burns...

From what I've been reading in tutorials and examples, this should be enought to use the `Session` in code as usual, and have it use the cache in the background. However, there have been seemingly random site crashes, which I've pinpointed down to the session not being populated. I'm getting null reference exceptions when trying to access data that was already put into the session.The only explanation I could come up with, was that the azure instances were switched, and the caching wasn't really distributed across the instances (I might be wrong, though).

I've also tried not using the session, but using a custom cookie instead, and then saving stuff in the cache and using the cookie value to retrieve the data from cache, but the same thing was happenning, so I'm guessing it's not the session but the underlying caching that's breaking.

As stated in the title the Azure version is 1.4. and it's quite possible that the examples I used were for newer versions. Switching to a newer version of Azure is not an option due to a lot of other libraries that might break.

Comment: Please note that Caching service is not persistent. It is a RAM storage by its nature. It may flush away. It happens rarely but still it can happen. A possible workaround is to use Azure SQL instead.